# ¿En que momento debo realizar un commit en git?

Tags: git

Estoy recién comenzando con git y si bien conozco muy bien su teoría comandos y demás me a costado acostumbrarme en la practica...

Digamos que estoy en un proyecto y me encuentro desarrollando la barra de navegación.. debo hacer el commit al tener la barra completamente lista o en cada paso de la construcción de la barra de navegación?

hacer commits del tipo: Barra de navegación añadida

o del tipo: - Estilos de barra lista 
            - Links de barra establecidos
etc etc. 
Gracias por sus respuestas !

Comment: Por preguntas como ésta ha habido guerras. Me temo que puede haber tantas respuestas como estilos de programación y que la pregunta se acabará cerrando porque atrae principalmente opiniones  (unos dirán que tantas veces como sea posible, otros dirán que sólo cuando esté completo, otros que solo una vez al día, otros que combinan métodos...)

Comment: Las respuestas están basadas en opiniones. La pregunta debería ser sobre un problema concreto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De forma general y no específicamente en Git siempre es recomendable hacer commits seguidos para tener tus cambios versionados y disponibles en el control de código fuente.

De manera específica en Git y respondiendo la pregunta específica que has formulado:

Suponiendo lo siguiente:

1. Tienes una tarea asignada cuya especificación es crear una barra de navegación
2. Estas trabajando en un [topic branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows#Topic-Branches) (también llamado feature branch)

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

- Si te sientes a gusto y confiado en que puedes entregar los cambios correspondientes a toda la especificación sin problemas ya que la tarea no es muy compleja, entonces bastará con un solo commit.
- Si la tarea es demasiado compleja, te recomendaría proponer dividir la tarea en varias subtareas de modo que puedas asociar cada paso particular de la construcción de por ejemplo la barra de navegación a un commit específico.
- Si la tarea es simple sin embargo consideras que te conviene mas realizar varios commits por el motivo que sea, por ejemplo porque quieres enteder mejor los cambios o te parece mas ordenado, entonces hazlo de esa manera, no hay ningún problema. Si de todas maneras hubiera una política de un checkin por tarea o si luego te arrepientes y consideras que has hecho muchos checkins para algo muy simple siempre tienes la posibilidad de juntarlos en uno solo antes de hacer `push` mediante lo que se conoce como [squash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode)

Al final lo mas importante que debes recordar es lo que menciona @Kristian Damian en su respuesta: Básicamente que cada checkin debe contener cambios que funcionalmente estén completos sin que rompa el código, unit test o proceso de build que tengas establecido.

El resto puede ser muy subjetivo y depende de cada caso y cada persona

Comment: Algo que me preocupaba es que cuando uno ve el log de un repositorio en el que se esta trabajando en equipo aparecerán todos los commits y pues me preguntaba si era molesto que un programador suba muchos commits... ya que por mas simple que sea la tarea me gusta tener todo bastante subdividido en todo caso como comentas puedo hacer todos los commits que me vengan en gana en mi maquina local y al concluir subir todo en un único commit con squash :D

Answer (score 2):

Como comenta Alvaro, es más cuestión de estilos, pero en las mejores [prácticas de git](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/) te invitan a hacer commit `temprano y seguido`

Una de las ventajas que obtendrías dando commit seguido es la posibilidad de volver a varios estados previos en caso de un bug difícil de rastrear, pero es importante tomar en cuenta que deberías establecer reglas mínimas para el commit como por ejemplo:

- Que el código no este roto (o compile dependiendo del lenguaje)
- Que el estado actual no rompa las pruebas unitarias
- Que no interfieras en el código de otro compañero

Básicamente se trata de ser un buen ciudadano con el resto de los integrantes del equipo o que facilites la clonación de tu rama